# SYBASE ASE 15.7 "blocksize" parameter in the "dump database"

Tags: sybase

In ASE 15.7 , is the blocksize parameter in dump database beneficial for performance ? I am referring to the "blocksize" parameter, in the "dump database" command.
For example:

```
dump database pubs2 to 'compress::/tmp/backup_pubs1.dmp'
stripe on '/tmp/backup_pubs2.dmp' 
with  
init, 
 notify=operator_console,
**blocksize=262144,**
compression=100
go
```

How can I verify if backup server is taking this value? I am checking the log of the dump but I see this all time:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxRdq.png)

Thank you!

Comment: `blocksize` was originally provided as a means of adjusting performance for dumps to tape; nowadays any benefits from using `blocksize` will likely be overshadowed by a host of other issues that can affect dump performance ... number of stripes, configuration of the dump devices' underlying disks and/or filesystems, the type of data in the database, the database devices themselves, and any compression options included in the `dump` command; your best bet would be to run some tests in your environment and see if you see any noticeable improvements

Comment: fwiw, I doubt you'll see any noticeable improvements with `blocksize` settings when dealing with such small databases like `pubs2`; also, your proposed `dump` command is mixing 2 different forms of compression ... `compress::` is a really old format and uses the oldest/slowest compression libraries (aka `1st generation`) while the `with ... compression=100` uses the newest/fastest compression libraries (aka `3rd generation`); I don't recommend mixing the different compression methods and would suggest sticking wtih `with ... compression=100`; (NOTE: `2nd generation` ==> `compression={0..9}`)

Comment: Yes, thank you. You are right, its a small example. I have tried without compression and this is the result: 

blocksize=262144 -->  real    0m20.101s
blocksize=4096  ---> real    0m20.063s

So, very similar.

Comment: Do you know any way to verify if the backup server is making the input/output in the size indicated with blocksize?

Comment: you could probably set some traceflags in the backupserver's RUNserver file (then bounce the backupserver) but at the moment I'm drawing a blank as to what the appropriate traceflag would be ...

Comment: per this [link](https://sybase-ase-rep-sags.blogspot.com/2010/01/tuning-backup-server-dump-and-load.html) you can dynamically set some traceflags; see the first paragraph under 'BACKUP SERVER TRACES' for an explanation of the codes; sample call (from within ASE): `SYB_BACKUP...qatraceon 0,1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I will review that information.